# Magento: contents of <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>

Tags: php, magento, templates, magento-1.7

I've been playing around with magento's PHP files.
However I cannot seem to figure out what gets pulled
out with

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
```

and from where this comes from. For instance, I can
see a some text that says "Home Page" but I cannot
find where this comes from by wading through the
various files under `/app/design/frontend/base/default`
and turning on template paths hints does not help.

The version of magento I am running is 1.7.0.2.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Jason, `getChildHtml()` and `toHtml()` are used everywhere. Check out my question here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42503/alter-tohtml-output-in-varien-form And to answer a comment you made below, example of my favorite tool is: `[~/www/app]# grep -rn "function getChildHtml" *` then to find usages related to shopping cart: `grep -rn "getChildHtml" * | grep cart`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the content block is a structural block used to wrap all blocks for page content.
getChildHtml('content')  loads all blocks which are added in layout "content" either by

```
1. xml via <reference name="content"><block type="core/template') name="test" template="test.phtml"/>

2. code via $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
```

the toHtml method of each block inside 'content' is called to return  its html

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem by going to CMS -> Pages -> Home page -> Content -> and deleting everything from the text area and saving changes.

Comment: yes and with the above knowledge you will find it without looking blindly through the system. i would advise you to do a search for the block name over the core code...

Comment: How can I set up my development environment for code search. Do I need an eclipse IDE or is the Unix command line enough?

Comment: What does the XML code you posted do? And especially, in what file should I place it to make it work? Is this a default layout statement or a layout update?

Comment: the xml does fetch the content block from layout and adds another block inside. you can put it in any Layout-XML-File active in the system.

Comment: How do I know which layout XML files are active in the system. If I name the file, say, layout.xml, then how do I activate the file?